# Use kaggle kernel inside kaggle notebook

Tags: kaggle

I want to use this command

```
!kaggle kernels output iliasparalikas/dcgan -p .
```

to download the outputs of the previous notebook to this one so i can continue training.It works fine in my local machine, but when I try to use it i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/bin/kaggle", line 5, in <module>
    from kaggle.cli import main
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kaggle/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    api.authenticate()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kaggle/api/kaggle_api_extended.py", line 403, in authenticate
    raise IOError('Could not find {}. Make sure it\'s located in'
OSError: Could not find kaggle.json. Make sure it's located in /root/.kaggle. Or use the environment method.
```

I know this means that I need the api key, which I have generated, but I have no idea where to place it. I have tried to copy it to /root/.kaggle but it still wont work.

Any ideas?